# How to access command prompt of windows from Android application

Tags: android, windows, interface

I have one requirement in my android application in which I need to run command on Windows/Linux command prompt from my android application. And this done when I connect my device to Computer. So friend please tell any suggestion, any help regarding with them or any way that I follow to do this task.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably isn't possible without some sort of SSH or telnet connection, which isn't what you're looking for. It's the host computer that needs to execute code from the device (like you might execute an EXE from a USB drive). I don't think the other way around is possible, at least not without some sort of driver exploit.

I know it's not ideal, but your best approach may be to have a helper program on the user's computer that will detect a plugin and then run when that occurs.

Comment: Yes, unless you want to try to create an autorun file full of commands on the sdcard and mount it to a (still trusting) PC, you are pretty much going to have to have custom software installed on the PC to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need to do is use telnet if im getting you right.

Comment: If the desktop PC were running a telnet server, and if you had achieved networking whereby the android device could initiate a connection to the PC, neither of which is likely to be the case.

Comment: Thanks Friends for reply, But telnet approach is totally depends on network, but I just want to access Local PC where device is connected, so how I can access it. Because in this I have no total access of PC like telnet. Also can any one suggest me which API of android or Java help full for this.

Comment: There are no APIs for this.  It's not a situation anticipated in the design of android, which seems to be based on the assumption that syncing is done using Internet servers/"the cloud"  You would likely need to build off of the developer tools (adb, etc) instead.